# Issues loading latest Kendo version using requireJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, requirejs

I'm attempting to use the latest 2016.2.504 with RequireJS, but it's not working ,I have tested with v2015.2.805 and it seems to work but can't get the same code to work with 2016.2.504,like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />

    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.1/require.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <kendo-grid options="mainGridOptions">
            <div k-detail-template>
                <kendo-tabstrip>
                <ul>
                    <li class="k-state-active">Orders</li>
                    <li>Contact information</li>
                </ul>
                <div>
                    <div kendo-grid k-options="detailGridOptions(dataItem)"></div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Country: <input ng-model="dataItem.Country" /></li>
                        <li>City: <input ng-model="dataItem.City" /></li>
                        <li>Address: {{dataItem.Address}}</li>
                        <li>Home phone: {{dataItem.HomePhone}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </kendo-tabstrip>
            </div>
        </kendo-grid>
    </div>
</div>


    <script>
      require.config({
          waitSeconds:0,
        paths: {
          "angular": "http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/js/angular.min",
          "jquery": "http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/js/jquery.min",
          "kendo.all.min": "http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/js/kendo.all.min"
        },
        shim: {
          "angular": { deps: ["jquery"] },
          "kendo.all.min": { deps: ["angular"] }
        }
      });

      require([ "angular", "kendo.all.min" ], function() {
        var app = angular.module("KendoDemos", ["kendo.directives"]);

        app.controller("controller", ["$scope", function($scope) {
          $scope.mainGridOptions = {
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Employees"
                    },
                    pageSize: 5,
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverSorting: true
                },
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                dataBound: function() {
                    this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
                },
                columns: [{
                    field: "FirstName",
                    title: "First Name",
                    width: "120px"
                    },{
                    field: "LastName",
                    title: "Last Name",
                    width: "120px"
                    },{
                    field: "Country",
                    width: "120px"
                    },{
                    field: "City",
                    width: "120px"
                    },{
                    field: "Title"
                }]
            };

            $scope.detailGridOptions = function(dataItem) {
                return {
                    dataSource: {
                        type: "odata",
                        transport: {
                            read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
                        },
                        serverPaging: true,
                        serverSorting: true,
                        serverFiltering: true,
                        pageSize: 5,
                        filter: { field: "EmployeeID", operator: "eq", value: dataItem.EmployeeID }
                    },
                    scrollable: false,
                    sortable: true,
                    pageable: true,
                    columns: [
                    { field: "OrderID", title:"ID", width: "56px" },
                    { field: "ShipCountry", title:"Ship Country", width: "110px" },
                    { field: "ShipAddress", title:"Ship Address" },
                    { field: "ShipName", title: "Ship Name", width: "190px" }
                    ]
                };
            };
        }]);

        angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But,it work like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.406/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.406/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.406/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.1/require.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="controller">
      <select kendo-drop-down-list k-options="options"></select>
    </div>

    <script>
      require.config({
          waitSeconds:0,
        paths: {
          "angular": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular.min",
          "jquery": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min",
          "kendo.all.min": "http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.406/js/kendo.all.min"
        },
        shim: {
          "angular": { deps: ["jquery"] },
          "kendo.all.min": { deps: ["angular"] }
        }
      });

      require([ "angular", "kendo.all.min" ], function() {
        var app = angular.module("app", ["kendo.directives"]);

        app.controller("controller", ["$scope", function($scope) {
          $scope.options = {
            dataSource: {
              data: [{name:"Jane Doe", value: 1}, {name:"John Doe", value: 2}]
            },
            dataTextField: "name",
            dataValueField: "value"
          };
        }]);

        angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help me how I resolve this issue.Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {`

instead of

`app.controller("controller", ["$scope", function($scope) {`

---

`angular.bootstrap(document, ["KendoDemos"]);`

instead of

`angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);`

---

[Here working example](http://dojo.telerik.com/@layonez/IMUri)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @Layonez Wronskey But it still throw an error Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=KendoDemos&p1=Error…A%2F%2Fkendo.cdn.telerik.com%2F2016.2.504%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463)

Comment: Thats not true, if these 2 issues correected all work perfect. Check out that dojo http://dojo.telerik.com/@layonez/IMUri

Comment: You solve my problem,it works well.But i dont't know why the browser throw the error,is it a bug?